# Updating Alchemy framework

Tags: a4t

Is there a way to update the Alchemy framework in the Content Manager without uninstalling the previous one?

I'm trying to update from version 0.6.2 to 0.7.0 and when I execute the msi installer, it tells me that there is another version, and I need to remove the existing one.

But if I remove the existing version before installing the new one, all my installed plugins disappear!
Am I missing something?

Comment: I would suggest that you report this problem as an issue to the Alchemy project. It's possible to make msi installers that also deal with updates. It's fiddlier, and more work, so I can imagine why they didn't do this for a beta release, however it sounds like it would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a button to update Alchemy from the Control Room, but it's currently listed as an experimental feature that you shouldn't use just yet.

So for now, I'd recommend just making a list of the plug-ins you use and re-install them afterwards (if they are indeed lost). It's not like it takes a long time to install them -- just click the button for each plugin :)

Comment: Yes, but Control Room is a feature of 0.7.0, so I haven't missed anything, and I have to reeinstall plugins, thanks.

Comment: I guess you could automate that part: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/install-a4t-plugin-an-alchemy4tridion-plugin-installer#more-3083

Comment: You could also download the plugin locally and then drag-n-drop it to install instead of the faster one-click install method...